# Which ORM's support the upsert statement?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, orm, upsert

For example, in Hibernate, there is the saveOrUpdate method, which does a select first, and depending on if there is a record available, it does and insert or an update. However, Oracle DB supports an 'upsert', in which you can do an insert or an update in one statement.

I know Hibernate doesn't support this out of the box, are there any other ORM's that support it? Also, has anyone managed to override Hibernate to support upserts?

Many thanks

Comment: It's not called "upsert" in Oracle. It's called `MERGE` (and I believe that's what the ANSI standard names it as well)

Comment: saveOrUpdate usually does not not select, it merely checks if the id is set or not and calls save or update